# Can't save changes to files in Codiad

Tags: concurrency, server, edit

I installed [Codiad](http://codiad.com/), because it looked a good way to edit our system being developed in a LAN server. However, I can't save any modifications to the files. I followed [this tutorial](https://github.com/Codiad/Codiad/wiki/Pathing-&-The-Workspace) to create a symbolic link to the system folder. But now I got the same error as the people [here](https://github.com/Codiad/Codiad/issues/870). This bug has almost a year. Anyone knows if the bug persists? If there's any workaround? Or perhaps a better solution for a local team to work with files in the local server? (Avoiding concurrent access problems, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I needed was to change the owner of the files to be edited to www-data:www-data (Apache user and group).